# Using Sass Script is it possible to retrieve the name of the file currently being compiled

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm writing some custom functions using Sass Script and need to get the name of the file that is being compiled.

The eventual outcome would be to generate a class name based on the file name of the file that's being compiled. Is it possible to get that file name using Sass Script? I can use `Dir.getwd` to get the working directory but can't seem to get the current file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your files through [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) as a preprocessing step before processing them with Sass. This lets you use Ruby's built in global variable `__FILE__` in your Sass source which will output the name of the current file, e.g.

```
/* style.scss */

div {
  p:after {
    content: "Hello, this is <%= __FILE__ %>";
  }
}
```

You could for example use the [Tilt Gem](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) to handle both processing steps:

```
require 'erb'
require 'sass'
require 'tilt'

erb = Tilt::ERBTemplate.new('style.scss')
scss = Tilt::ScssTemplate.new{ erb.render }

result = scss.render
```

The output with the above scss file would be:

```
div p:after {
  content: "Hello, this is style.scss"; }
```

Comment: Cool, that seems like a good solution. My main problem with this would be that the call to the function currently sits in a file that is imported and I want to get the name of the file it was imported into (it needs to be in a central location). Am I right in thinking this would return _partial.scss instead of style.scss? I didn't konw about ERB or Tilt though which both seem like they could be useful